# The 'q' modifier in the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

If you go to the Graph API Explorer and append "/posts" to a user ID, then in the box on the side, one of the "modifiers" you can select is "q". Is this for searches? I didn't see it in the documentation and using it returns an OAuth error.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all possible parameters in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/feed

The "q" parameter is for the Search API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search